# Woocommerce email variables not converting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce admin email title we use the variables {order_number} and {order_date}, but they are not converting.

See: http://prntscr.com/jqltm8

All plugins, theme and WP are up to date.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax to get order Number is not correct , please replace your subject with

```
New Order ({order_number}) - {order_date}
```

Comment: Then it is conflicting with one of your plugin, try deactivate plugin one by one and check if it's works
It is conflicting with other plugin mail function

Comment: Yep! Disabled WPML and it started working again, thanks!

Comment: Check for fix: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/woocommerce-email-variables-dont-parse/

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like this, it should work:

```
[{site_title}] New Order ({order_number}) – {order_date}
```